# How to use a column from one workbook, iterate through another and copy the corresponding data over

Tags: python, excel, tkinter

I have two excel workbooks. One is a list of names (10-15k) in column A and 1-3 digit number in column B. The second only has a list of names in column A. I want to upload both files then iter the names from workbook2 through workbook1 and receive workbook3 that would only have names that did not appear in workbook1 with a 0 in the next column over. I'm trying to do this with tkinter so it can be an executable program for some coworkers.

I'm pretty new at coding so I'm getting a bit lost. What I have so far is below and I'm sure there are mistakes :(

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import messagebox
import pandas as pd

root= tk.Tk()

canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width = 400, height = 300, bg = 'lightsteelblue2', relief = 'raised')
canvas1.pack()

label1 = tk.Label(root, text='Interaction Comparison', bg = 'lightsteelblue2')
label1.config(font=('bookman old style', 20))
canvas1.create_window(200, 40, window=label1)

def getCSV1 ():
    global read_file1

    import_file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    read_file = pd.read_csv (import_file_path)

browseButton_CSV1 = tk.Button(text="      Import Interaction CSV File     ", command=getCSV1, bg='green', fg='white', font=('bookman old style', 12, 'bold'))
canvas1.create_window(200, 110, window=browseButton_CSV1)

def getCSV2 ():
    global read_file2

    import_file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    read_file = pd.read_csv (import_file_path)

browseButton_CSV2 = tk.Button(text="      Import Comparison CSV File     ", command=getCSV2, bg='green', fg='white', font=('bookman old style', 12, 'bold'))
canvas1.create_window(200, 160, window=browseButton_CSV2)

def convertToCSV ():
    global read_file1, read_file2
    data = pd.read_csv
    for i in read_file1.data.iterrows(read_file2):
        print (i)



    export_file_path = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension='.csv')
    read_file.to_csv (export_file_path, index = None, header=True)

saveAsButton_CSV = tk.Button(text='CSV Comparison', command=convertToCSV, bg='green', fg='white', font=('bookman old style', 12, 'bold'))
canvas1.create_window(200, 210, window=saveAsButton_CSV)

def exitApplication():
    MsgBox = tk.messagebox.askquestion ('Exit Application','Are you sure you want to exit the application',icon = 'warning')
    if MsgBox == 'yes':
       root.destroy()

exitButton = tk.Button (root, text='       Exit Application     ',command=exitApplication, bg='brown', fg='white', font=('bookman old style', 12, 'bold'))
canvas1.create_window(200, 260, window=exitButton)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: if you are ok to use pandas you can use merge method to have a look on -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61923715/python-the-best-way-to-create-a-new-dataframe-from-two-other-dataframes-with-d/61927143#61927143

Comment: That seems to work for just printing it in the output and giving the excel names as suggested in that answer. But I would like it to be an input of excel files as I have suggested above by using tkinter to upload 2 files then using that merge to create a new file. Any idea on how I can combine the two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out what my issue was. Thank you to [Hietsh Kumar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62334855/how-to-use-a-column-from-one-workbook-iterate-through-another-and-copy-the-corr#comment110250822_62334855) for the reference to the merge method!

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import messagebox
import pandas as pd

root= tk.Tk()

canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width = 400, height = 300, bg = 'lightsteelblue2', relief = 'raised')
canvas1.pack()

label1 = tk.Label(root, text='Interaction Comparison', bg = 'lightsteelblue2')
label1.config(font=('bookman old style', 20))
canvas1.create_window(200, 40, window=label1)

def getExcel1 ():
    global df1
    
    import_file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    df1 = pd.read_excel (import_file_path)
    
browseButton_CSV1 = tk.Button(text="      Import Interaction Excel File     ", command=getExcel1, bg='green', fg='white', font=('bookman old style', 12, 'bold'))
canvas1.create_window(200, 110, window=browseButton_CSV1)

def getExcel2 ():
    global df2
    
    import_file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    df2 = pd.read_excel (import_file_path)
    
browseButton_CSV2 = tk.Button(text="      Import Comparison Excel File     ", command=getExcel2, bg='green', fg='white', font=('bookman old style', 12, 'bold'))
canvas1.create_window(200, 160, window=browseButton_CSV2)

def combinetoExcel ():
   
    df = pd.merge(df1,df2[['Alias','Interactions']], on = 'Alias', how = 'left')

    df.to_excel('List.xlsx', index = False)


saveAsButton_CSV = tk.Button(text='Excel List', command=combinetoExcel, bg='green', fg='white', font=('bookman old style', 12, 'bold'))
canvas1.create_window(200, 210, window=saveAsButton_CSV)

def exitApplication():
    MsgBox = tk.messagebox.askquestion ('Exit Application','Are you sure you want to exit the application',icon = 'warning')
    if MsgBox == 'yes':
       root.destroy()
     
exitButton = tk.Button (root, text='       Exit Application     ',command=exitApplication, bg='brown', fg='white', font=('bookman old style', 12, 'bold'))
canvas1.create_window(200, 260, window=exitButton)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Great , if post on the link was useful you can upvote for others reference