# Merge two dataframes with column contains dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, zip

I have 2 dataframes questions, answers:

Questions:

```
productId        question        questionId    total_answers
---------        --------        ----------    -------------
147374           I wear Tan       4475521            2
                 Sand w/ Yellow
                 undertone ..
```

Answers:

```
productId       questionId     answerId      answer
---------       ----------     --------      ------
147374           4475521        123456       answer1
147374           4475521        654321       answer2
```

I want the result like this format:

```
productId     questionId      answers
---------     ----------      -------
147374         4475521        [{'answerId':'123456','answer':'answer1'},
                               {'answerId' :'654321','answer':'answer2'}]
```

Comment: What you have done?

Comment: It doesn't seem so difficult, what issues have you run into?

Comment: @Vidal result = pd.merge(questions, answers, on='questionId')

Comment: @Datanovice the difficulty is transform answers dataframe to one columns contains answers columns as keys of dictionary

Comment: just and example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61923715/python-the-best-way-to-create-a-new-dataframe-from-two-other-dataframes-with-d/61927143#61927143